# Get Payer Email from Webhook Event

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-rest-sdk

How can I retrieve the payers email address from a webhook event using the .NET SDK?  I need the email to create a purchase with LeadDyno.

**UPDATE**
Here's how you do it...

```
var requestBody = string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
            {
                requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            JObject webhookEvent = JObject.Parse(requestBody);
```

payerEmail = webhookEvent["resource"]["payer"]["payer_info"]["email"].ToString();

Comment: did you find the solution man ?

Comment: Yeah, you have to get the webhook event from the request, put it into a JObject, and navigate to it. Updarted my question